# Send mail using localhost SMTP

Tags: c#, iis-6, smtp

I am trying to setup SMTP server on IIS for sending mails. The SMTP server is intended to be used by the ASP.NET code in C#.

I was previously using gmail smtp wherein i provided the smtp.gmail.com as host with secure port and my gmail uid/pwd. That worked fine. Here is the code used to do that.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uname,pwd);
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Now i am planning to use the localhost SMTP server on IIS, **what values should i be giving for the parameters UseDefaultCredentials and Credentials.** I will be assigning false to EnableSsl as it's over port 25.

Also, what could be the most simple SMTP virtual server configuration.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think in localhost you can use :

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: Did you start the IIS SMTP service?

Comment: yes, but it still doesn't work(I have win8, but as I understand, I activated everything right). should I write smth like  "<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="..."><network defaultCredentials="true" host="localhost" port="25" /></smtp>" to web config? it is still "unknown smtp host", if I just write these 3 lines

Comment: IIS no longer has SMTP, it was removed.

Answer (score 30):

When you are using the local IIS SMTP service, set the DeliveryMethod to PickupDirectoryFromIis.  For example:

```
  smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
```

This totally bypasses the network layer, and writes the messages directly to disk. Its much faster than going through the chatty SMTP protocol.

When you using the above code, it means you can get rid of this part of your code:

```
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uname,pwd);
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for using the local IIS pickup directory.  Since it just writes a file, it won't use any credentials at all and IIS will just send it for you.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you configure the smtp server.  You might not need to use any credentials at all, and just configure the server to only accept local connections.

Comment: @Joel:
My SMTP server setup:
Authentication: Anonymous access
IP address: All Unassigned
Outbound security: Anonymous access

Curious, if this is a correct configuration for sending mails without credentials.

Comment: That's a question for serverfault.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test emails in localhost, just download install the papercut tool [https://papercut.codeplex.com/](https://papercut.codeplex.com)

and change hostname to localhost as below. Papercut captures  all  the emails sending using localhost.

```
  smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
    smtpClient.Port = 587;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uname,pwd);
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: also smtp4dev is a local smtp server for developers.

Comment: also TestMailServerTool:
original (download seems to be broken):
https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

backup: 
https://github.com/Serjster/TestMailServerTool

Comment: I already had Host and Credentials but for me (using Sendgrid) the fix was adding EnableSsl and the 587 port.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried enabling relay?

Find IIS6 manager (I have found that searching for IIS may return 2 results) go to the SMTP server properties then 'Access' then press the relay button.

Then you can either select all or only allow certain ip's like 127.0.0.1

[image: SMTP Relay]

Comment: I am using CDOSYS and from server where this virtual server is setup emails are sending smoothly, but when I try my utility from workstation get 'Transport fail to connect to server' message. any idea? what I need to change in my code so workstation will also able to use this virtual SMTP server and can send emails.

Answer (score 1):

Tx Natim, what you say worked for me. Have our intranet app using integrated auth with our exchange 2007 server now:

```
Dim msg As New MailMessage()
Dim smtp As SmtpClient

msg.From = New MailAddress(strFrom)
msg.To.Add(strTo)
msg.Subject = strSubject
msg.Body = strBody

smtp = New SmtpClient("ServerName")
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
smtp.Send(msg)
```