# SMTP server name and port

Tags: asp.net, smtp

I am trying to send an email using a simple button in asp.net. But I am getting following error-`"The transport failed to connect to the server"`.

```
  SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
```

I've used `localhost` because,I don't know `smtp server` name of my computer..
how can i fix it? how can I know the `SMTP server` name?? My `os` is `win xp`
hope someone can help me...

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server installed on your computer?

Comment: @Sudheesh: Is the SMTP server running?  Is it listening on standard ports?  Can you check the SMTP server's logs and see if there's anything useful there?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Figure out smtp server host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461154/figure-out-smtp-server-host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test email locally set up a [drop folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164241.aspx) called 'maildrop' on your C:\ drive and add the following to your Web.Config file:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod='SpecifiedPickupDirectory'>
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\maildrop" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

[ASP.NET: Using pickup directory for outgoing e-mails](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/27/asp-net-using-pickup-directory-for-outgoing-e-mails.aspx)

**UPDATE:**

You should be using the newer email library...

**using System.Net.Mail;**

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(); 
msg.To = "sudheej.j800@outlook.com"; 
msg.From = "sudheej.j800@gmail.com"; 
msg.Subject = "hi"; 
msg.Body = "yes"; 

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("localhost");
smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Nothing in the maildrop folder? This should work... show the code where you create and set the SmtpClient object and port property.

Comment: MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
         msg.To = "sudheej.j800@outlook.com";
          msg.From = "sudheej.j800@gmail.com";
          msg.Subject = "hi";
    msg.Body = "yes";
   SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
 
                                             
    SmtpMail.Send(msg);

Comment: thanks so much
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25

now this is the error..

Comment: <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="">
        <network defaultCredentials="true" host="localhost" password=""
          userName="" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

it may work

Answer (score 0):

Standard SMTP runs on port 25. If you don't have anything listening on port 25 on your machine, then you likely don't have an SMTP server running. Try:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

and see if that connects to something. I ssupect not (i.e. you don't have an SMTP server on localhost)

Answer (score 0):

You need a SMTP server on your machine before do that.

Comment: I think this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557989/send-mail-using-localhost-smtp

Comment: You can use your gmail account to test it!!