# sending email from contact page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, email

Iam developing in visual studio 2010 I would like to send email from the contact page I have my code listed below it executes without errors but the email is not sending

```
Partial Class _Default
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Actions when the Send button is clicked.
  ''' </summary>
  Protected Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click

    'Create instance of main mail message class.
    Dim mailMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()

    'Configure mail mesage
    'Set the From address with user input
    '    mailMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(txtFromAddress.Text.Trim())
    'Get From address in web.config
    mailMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("fromEmailAddress"))
    'Another option is the "from" attirbute in the <smtp> element in the web.config.

    'Set additinal addresses
    mailMessage.To.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(txtToAddress.Text.Trim()))
    'mailMessage.CC
    'mailMessage.Bcc
    'mailMessage.ReplyTo

    'Set additional options
    mailMessage.Priority = Net.Mail.MailPriority.High
    'Text/HTML
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = False

    'Set the subjet and body text
    mailMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text.Trim()
    mailMessage.Body = txtBody.Text.Trim()

    'Add one to many attachments
    'mailMessage.Attachments.Add(New System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:\temp.txt")

    'Create an instance of the SmtpClient class for sending the email
    Dim smtpClient As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()

    'Use a Try/Catch block to trap sending errors
    'Especially useful when looping through multiple sends
    Try
      smtpClient.Send(mailMessage)
    Catch smtpExc As System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
      'Log error information on which email failed.
    Catch ex As Exception
      'Log general errors
    End Try

    End Sub
End Class

     <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb"           Inherits="_Default" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
      <title>Send Email</title>
       </head>
       <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
       <p>
        From:<br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromAddress" runat="server" Columns="35" /></p>
       <p>
       To:<br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtToAddress" runat="server" Columns="35" /></p>
      <p>
       Subject:<br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Columns="50" /></p>
      <p>
        Body:<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" Columns="75" TextMode="MultiLine"      Rows="6" /></p>
        <p>
         <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send Mail" /></p>
     </div>
   </form>
  </body>
  </html>

 web config 


     <?xml version="1.0"?>
             <!-- 

      -->
       <configuration>
    <!--Externalize From address-->
    <appSettings>
    <add key="fromEmailAddress" value="syntaxDon@gmail.com"/>
    </appSettings>
    <!--Externalize From address-->
    <connectionStrings/>
    <!--Mail settings-->
    <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
        <network host="\localhost:"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <!--Mail settings-->
    <system.web>
    <!-- 
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.

        Visual Basic options:
        Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
        where data loss can occur. 
        Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true"    targetFramework="4.0">
     </compilation>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
          <namespaces>
            <clear/>
            <add namespace="System"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
            <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
            <add namespace="System.Text"/>
            <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
            <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
            <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
        </namespaces>
       </pages>
       <!--
           The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
         -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
          The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
          of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
          during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
          it enables developers to configure html error pages 
          to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
       </customErrors>
      -->
     </system.web>
```

Comment: your question makes no sense... please clarify step by step what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind `btnSend_Click` handler to the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send Mail" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
```

Comment: ok I tried that but  to no avail , is my web config correct because Iam trying to send from localhost

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557989/send-mail-using-localhost-smtp